# PHP remember url parameter value using $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

I made a script that shows the value of "**school_id**" in url parameter.

```
http://mywebsite.com/mygrade?school_id=00000
```

I use **$_GET['school_id']** to display the ID number.

```
<?php echo $_GET['school_id']; ?>
```

But I what I want is if the parameter "**school_id**" is empty, I want to display the previous data entered.

Example, the user already browse http://mywebsite.com/mygrade?school_id=00000 then he browse **http://mywebsite.com/mygrade?school_id=** which id has no value. It will still display **00000** which is the previous ID he used.

I used this code below but doesn't work.. :(

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['schoo_id'] = $_GET['school_id'];

if ($_GET['school_id'] === null || $_GET['school_id'] == ""){
    echo $_SESSION['schoo_id'];
}
else{
    $_GET['school_id'];
}
?>
```

Anyone who get my point and could help me?

Comment: You modify the code so that the session variable is overwritten if get variable is set.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to break this down line by line, please let me know in the comments if I need to explain anything further:

Self explanatory:

```
<?php
session_start();
```

There is a typo here:

```
$_SESSION['schoo_id'] = $_GET['school_id'];
```

But! Fixing it won't resolve your problem. What happens if `$_GET['school_id']` is not defined/blank? Guess what, `$_SESSION['school_id']` is now blank. Obviously you don't want this behavior, so you'll want to *only set `$_SESSION['school_id']` if `$_GET['school_id']` is defined*

accessing `$_GET['school_id']` will throw an [E_NOTICE](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php#errorfunc.constants.errorlevels.e-parse) error if it isn't defined, so you'll want to instead check its existence, rather than checking to see if it is `null`.

```
if ($_GET['school_id'] === null || $_GET['school_id'] == ""){
```

Oh, that typo was intended. Why misspell school though? No need! :)

```
    echo $_SESSION['schoo_id'];
```

What is this doing? Nothing! No echo, nothing. Just accessing a variable and doing nothing with it.

```
}
else{
    $_GET['school_id'];
}
?>
```

Here's what your code should look like, or at least I believe is what you intend:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_GET['school_id']) && $_GET['school_id'] !== ""){
    $_SESSION['school_id'] = $_GET['school_id'];
}

// $_SESSION['school_id'] will be guaranteed to be what $_GET['school_id'] is (if set)
// or whatever it was last time it was defined
// always echo it.
echo $_SESSION['school_id'];
?>
```

Comment: Use `!==` instead of `!=` to check empty strings.

Comment: Good call. My original code would not have worked if the user entered "0".

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start(); 


if ($_GET['school_id'] === null || $_GET['school_id'] == ""){
    echo $_SESSION['schoo_id'];
}
else{
    $_GET['school_id'];
    $_SESSION['schoo_id'] = $_GET['school_id']; //here set the session
}
?>
```

Comment: in the case where $_GET['school_id'] is null, nothing is echoed.

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do here is save the GET value in SESSION only if it is set for later use so this should work

```
<?php
session_start(); 
if (!isset($_GET['school_id']) || $_GET['school_id'] === null || $_GET['school_id'] == ""){
    echo $_SESSION['schoo_id'];
}
else{
$_SESSION['schoo_id'] = $_GET['school_id'];
   echo  $_GET['school_id'];
}
?>
```

Comment: you have `isset` wrapping all of your conditions, I don't believe that was what was intended.

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it.

```
<?php

session_start(); 


if (isset($_GET['school_id']) && trim($_GET['school_id']) !== '') {
    // its a fair assumption to make that 'school_id' is intended to be an integer,
    // however I will not make that assumption on the OP's behalf.
    $_SESSION['school_id'] = $_GET['school_id'];
}

if (isset($_SESSION['school_id']) {
    echo $_SESSION['school_id'];
}
else {
    echo 'have not entered a school id yet';
}
?>
```

Comment: Do not use `empty` to check for empty strings.

Comment: @SalmanA I see what you mean `$i='0'; empty($i); /* true */`, thanks for the tip. I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with **Salman A**, the simplest way:

```
<?php
session_start(); 

if (is_int($_GET['school_id'])) $_SESSION['school_id'] = $_GET['school_id'];
// further use $_SESSION['school_id'] for your needs.

?>
```